# Traefik, EKS, TLS Termination, X-Forwarded-For

Tags: ssl, traefik, amazon-eks, x-forwarded-for

Deploying Traefik on EKS cluster. Need to terminate the TLS session using the ALB and also pass the X-Forwarded-For header. Running Traefik v2.4.8 using official helm chart ( `traefik/traefik` from `https://helm.traefik.io/traefik` )

There is already an AWS managed certificate present `arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxx:certificate/xxx`. I can manually set the DNS CNAME to point the ALB. No need to automate that.

What overrides are needed for Traefik helm chart, and also how to configure Ingress and/or IngressRoute to terminate TLS session on AWS ALB and populate the X-Forwarded-For header?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem/layout yet. Do you want to run traefik behind AWS ALB? Is there a reason why you need both?

Comment: @antaxify, ALBs have certain limits that can be solved by using traefik as an ingress controller, behind an ALB

Comment: @antaxify, I need Traefik for its powerful capabilities. Based on my experience Traefik will always be behind an ALB. How else can the Traefik proxy be exposed to internet.

Comment: You could go with a network loadbalancer (layer 4) and do SSL termination on traefik directly. Not sure about integration the AWS managed certifacte though - no experience with that. We use traefik behind network loadbalancers together with traefik and cert-manager and are quite happy with it.